# Manage class MovieClip

Tags: arrays, class, actionscript, movieclip

How can i change animation of a child movie clip, which is associated with a class, and was imported to array?

Right now i am able to make it dissapear when player hits it, with this line:

```
this.parent.removeChild(this);
```

There have a look at it, there are 2 mines which were imported with external as. file and are in MineList array.

http://teroute.com/stronghold/index.php?page=secret-project

I want to make those mines to explode when touched.

Here, more code:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < MineList.length; i++) // Here i count all mines, that are in MineList Array
{
    if(player.hitTestObject(MineList[i])) // If player touches any mine
    {
        MineList[i].removeSelf(); // If player touches a mine, 
                                  // then this mine will dissapear
    }
}
```

Here a removeSelf function which is in as. external file:

```
public function removeSelf():void
{
    trace("Removed");
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop) // Sustabdyti loop
    this.parent.removeChild(this); // panaikinimas
}
```

I think this line should be changed:

```
this.parent.removeChild(this);
```

To something like:

```
this.parent.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

But I'm doing it wrong, please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.parent.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

means you are telling the flash to goto and play from the second frame of the mine's parent. If you want to play the mine from it's second frame then you should write something like below

```
this.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

*Always check the scope or what you are accessing to ensure the things done correctly*.